# On using DiracDelta[t] in OutputResposne in version 10. Different result from version 9

Tags: control-systems

I am baffled by this. I was trying to run same example I had working in version 9.01 and found now I get empty plots.

The example is [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/KERNEL/KEse15.htm#x18-1700015) . Here is a simplified version of the above. The same exact example produces a plot in version 9.01. But in Version 10, it is empty.

[image]

```
w = 1; z = 0.07;
sys = TransferFunctionModel[w^2/(s^2 + 2 z*w*s + w^2), s];
fun = First@OutputResponse[sys, DiracDelta[t], {t, 0, 20}];
Plot[Evaluate[%], {t, 0, 20}]
```

I tried to find what is going on, so I asked for analytical solution, in version 10 it says:

```
w = 1; z = 0.07;
sys = TransferFunctionModel[w^2/(s^2 + 2 z*w*s + w^2), s];
fun = First@OutputResponse[sys, DiracDelta[t], t] // ComplexExpand // Simplify // Chop
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version 9.01:

```
w = 1; z = 0.07;
sys = TransferFunctionModel[w^2/(s^2 + 2 z*w*s + w^2), s];
fun = First@OutputResponse[sys, DiracDelta[t], t] // ComplexExpand // Simplify // Chop
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So in version 10 the solution seems to be reversed. going back in time !

```
 Plot[Evaluate[fun], {t, -20, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any idea what is going on? What changes could have caused this?

Comment: I see this issue too (version 10 on Mac OS X). The result is correct if I replace the delta function by `1000 HeavisideTheta[1/1000-t]`. Seems like this would have to be called a bug...

Comment: @Nasser: Version 8, Windows, give the same result as your Version 9. Best regards, Wolfgang

Comment: @Nasser, pls follow the suggestion from Jens. I will provide a more elaborate answer on why the behavior changed.

Comment: @Nasser many thanks for placing the question.  I have the same problem on my mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions 8 and 9, `OutputResponse` (and `StateResponse`) was doing its own processing of `DiracDelta`, before passing stuff on to `NDSolve`, etc. This was creating issues as `NDSolve` and the others were being constantly improved and updated. Now we let the core functions handle the preprocessing, but then we have to deal with a little quirk (aka bug) like this. The behavior you are seeing is just propagating upward from those functions.

```
eqs[Δ_] := {y[t] + 0.14 y'[t] + y''[t] == DiracDelta[t - Δ], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};

Δ = {0, 0.001};
y[t] /. DSolve[eqs[#], y[t], t] & /@ Δ;
Plot[%, {t, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Δ]
```

[image]

```
y[t] /. NDSolve[eqs[#], y[t], {t, 0, 20}] & /@ Δ;
Plot[%, {t, 0, 20}, PlotLegends -> Δ]
```

[image]

Comment: Does it mean that OutputReponse can only be used with DeltaDirac if one follows the trick shown above( fun = First@OutputResponse[sys, DiracDelta[t - 10^-27], t] // 
    ComplexExpand // Simplify // Chop) ?  Shouldn't a note be added to OutputResponse help on Mathematica?

Comment: @Ed Mendes: Well, features need to be documented, but bugs need to be fixed!

Comment: Possible issues would do while bugs are not fixed!

Comment: It seems that the bug was not fixed on 10.0.1.0 too.

Comment: @Ed Mendes, the fix should be in the next release.