# StateResponse is non-deterministic

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I observed non-deterministic behaviour in StateResponse. Let's look at an example.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{StateResponse[StateSpaceModel[TransferFunctionModel[{{1/(s + 1)}}, s]],
                             UnitBox[Mod[t/3, 1]],
                             {t, 0, 10}],
               UnitBox[Mod[t/3, 1]]}],
     {t, 0, 10},
     PlotRange -> All]
```

This yields a non-deterministic result, namely
[image: 1st plot]

and

[image: 2nd plot]

The reason is obviously the discontinuity of the input at t=0. When I choose as input e.g.

```
UnitBox[Mod[t/3 + 0.1, 1]]
```

the result is deterministic.

Why does this happen and how can one obtain deterministic results?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site.

Comment: I replaced the example with a very basic one that also exhibits non-deterministic behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what the problem is, since as user, do not have access to internal code. But it has to do with the handling of UnitBox in StateResponse.

> how can one obtain deterministic results

The work around is very simple. Make the definition of the UnitBox outside the call with NumericQ argument. Then it works. Like this:

```
f[t_?NumericQ] := UnitBox[t];
Plot[Evaluate[{StateResponse[StateSpaceModel[
  TransferFunctionModel[{{1/(s + 1)}}, s]], f[Mod[t/3, 1]], {t, 0, 10}], 
    UnitBox[Mod[t/3, 1]]}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

So instead of calling `UnitBox[Mod[t/3, 1]]` call `f[Mod[t/3, 1]]` It might have been due to symbolic processing of UnitBox. With `NumericQ`, it forces different numerical path internally and bypasses the original problem.

Version 10.1 on windows

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, I don't understand the fix. For any t in [0,10] the expression Mod[t/3,1] is numeric. So how is this different from using UnitBox directly?

Comment: @Mathxy As I said, I do not know internally what happens. CLearly this is a bug, but you asked for a workaround. There was some changes in v10 with processing of diracdelta's in control system. May be this is related. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57891/on-using-diracdeltat-in-outputresposne-in-version-10-different-result-from-ve

Comment: @Mathxy btw, It might be a good idea to send this to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer and the workaround. I just don't understand how NumericQ fixes the problem.